# Is there any easy way to output a 3rd user-agent of a web-spider?

Tags: web-services, user-agent

I am wondering is there any public service that can check the useragent on another server.

For example, I can ask Facebook to parse my website and Facebook will use a UA with a "facebookexternalhit" string in it. To see it I have to prepare somecode on the server side, logged it somewhere.

Is there any easier way or service that I can do it without my own server?

Thanks,

Comment: Question looks like search for tools in current form... Also very unclear what you actually trying to check if you don't own the server. Getting information  about someone else servers (like IIS/Apache/whatever logs) is possible, but I can't think of any legal way of doing so :)

Comment: Just want to know the user agent for linkis.com :P currently don't have a server on my hand :(

Comment: You may get better chance of getting answer if you ask precise question on proper site (which likely should be webmasters SE)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're thinking of the "Referer" HTTP header field, rather than the user-agent?

When I looked at linkis.com functionality, it seemed to be a URL shortener that puts a customized frame on the page, so the visits to the third party site will always be the actual end user, not a bot/spider. The only way you'll know the visit originated from the linkis.com link will be if the user's browser sends the Referer header, which is not guaranteed by the way.

Separately, http://www.user-agents.org/ does not list anything for  linkis.com, but it's a useful reference for other user-agent strings.

Comment: user-agents.org has only a few hundred user agents listed but, here you could research and download 4.5 million agents: http://ua.theafh.net/